Arduino and Pololu Motor Driver Shield Undervoltage Issue When Driving Relay and Motor Pump
Problem: Arduino Relay Shuts Off When Motor Driver Turns on to Actuate Motor/Pump.
Hello! This is my first post, so pardon if my question lacks structure or etiquette. I will try to provide as much detail as possible.
Some background on what I am trying to do is that I am trying to create an “automated disk brake” system (not to be used on vehicles, don't worry), where I can control the pressure in the brake line using a hydraulic pump controlled via Arduino. Since the pump can't run for an extended period of time, I also have a normally closed in-line solenoid valve in order to “lock” the pressure in the brake line. The solenoid valve is activated with 24 V and 0.4 A, and so in order to control this with an Arduino, I have a 5 V relay that the Arduino can switch through a digital pin. The relay draws about 0.07 A of current at full load, so there is also a FET between the Arduino and relay to prevent too much current draw from the Arduino by the control pin on the relay.
As for the hydraulic pump, it has two power wires, a control wire, and a fourth that can be ignored. The hydraulic pump takes in 12 V and 40 A on the two power wires, and a PWM voltage between 0-12 V on the control wire (max draw about 2 A when I tested with a multimeter. I have a motor driver shield (The Pololu 24v18 Dual G2 High Power Motor Driver) hooked up to the Arduino in order to generate this PWM voltage. The shield has protections built-in to protect the Arduino.
So, the problem that I am having is that I need to be able to open the solenoid valve, and then once the valve is open, it needs to stay open as I build up pressure in the brake line using the hydraulic pump. However, when I activate the solenoid valve, and then subsequently activate the hydraulic pump, the solenoid valve suddenly turns off. I can include my super simple code that I used to test it, but I believe it is some hardware issue because the indicator light on the relay turns off, yet the code says the relay should still be on. When the hydraulic pump turns on, the digital pin (that is supposed to be written HIGH) suddenly drops to zero volts.
My first thought is that this is either due to power fluctuations or noise from the power supply I have hooked up, so I tried to independently power my Arduino with USB power and not via the Shield's provided power. I also hooked the solenoid valve on a separate 24 V power supply, and the pump on its own 12 V power, and the relay is powered by its own 5 V as well. (Still does not work).
Note: Everything works as expected on its own, the relay can switch the solenoid, and the pump can run with all PWM voltages on its own. It's just when they are both connected to the Arduino that somehow they affect each other.
Image of rough schematic (I forgot to draw it, but VIN on the driver is connected to +24 V, and GND on the driver is connected to negative end of power supply):

Code snippet:
DualG2HighPowerMotorShield24v18 md; 

bool solenoidState = false;  //off
bool pumpState     = false;  //off
int  choice        = 0; 
unsigned int motorCurrent = 0;

void getMotorData() { 
  delay(1); 
  for(int i=0; i<10; i++) {
    motorCurrent = motorCurrent + md.getM2CurrentMilliamps(); 
    delayMicroseconds(100); 
  }

  motorCurrent = motorCurrent/10; 

  //shut motors off at 8 amps to avoid damager to power supply and motor
  if(motorCurrent > 8000) { 
    md.disableM2Driver(); 
    while(1); 
  }

  //force motor current to be zero below 250mA (idle current when motor if OFF hovers between 250-300mA)
  else if (motorCurrent < 150) { 
    motorCurrent = 0; 
  }
}

void setup() {
  // put your setup code here, to run once:
  pinMode(8, OUTPUT);
  Serial.begin(9600);
  while(!Serial);
  md.init();
  md.calibrateM2CurrentOffset();
  md.enableM2Driver();
  delay(1);
  md.setM2Speed(0);
}

void loop() {
  // put your main code here, to run repeatedly:
  getMotorData();
  Serial.println("\nSolenoidState: ");
  Serial.println(solenoidState); 
  Serial.println("PumpState: "); 
  Serial.println(pumpState); 
  Serial.println("Motor Current: ");
  Serial.println(motorCurrent);

  Serial.println("Input (1: OnSoli, 2: OffSoli, 3:OnPump, 4: OffPump): "); 
  delay(100);
  while(Serial.available() == 0); 
  delay(100);
  choice = Serial.parseInt(); 
  delay(100);
  Serial.println(choice);

  Serial.print(".\n.\n.\n");

  if (choice == 0) {
    Serial.println("no action"); 
  } else if (choice == 1) { 
    Serial.println("turning solenoid on");
    solenoidState = 1;
    digitalWrite(8, HIGH); 
  } else if (choice == 2) { 
    Serial.println("turning solenoid off"); 
    solenoidState = 0;
    digitalWrite(8, LOW); 
  } else if (choice == 3) { 
    Serial.println("turning pump on"); 
    pumpState = 1;
    md.enableM2Driver();
    delay(100);
    md.setM2Speed(125); 
  } else if (choice == 4) { 
    Serial.println("turning pump off"); 
    pumpState = 0;
    md.disableM2Driver(); 
    delay(100);
    md.setM2Speed(0); 
  } 

  Serial.println("end loop");
  Serial.println(" ");
}

Link to driver shield specs
Link to pump
Link to relay

I found out what the problem was, despite me cutting the trace on Pin 8 of the Motor Driver Shield like the website mentioned (in order to decouple Pin 8 of the Arduino from the Shield), whenever md.setM2Speed() was called, pin 8 got pulled down to zero volts. This could be because I didn't properly cut the trace so Pin 8 was still connected to the shield's Motor 2 Dir Input, or because of some other erroneous behavior that I didn't know about. I changed the pin that connected the Arduino to the Relay to a different pin (i.e. pin 13) and it worked. I think I probably need a bigger board with more GPIO pins as to avoid overlapping functions in the future.
